How can I provide a default configuration for all Aspire Services?
I want to provide a set of configuration defaults for all my services. Those defaults should be managed by the AppHost or another shared Assembly.
So here are the relevant code snippets:
AppHost/appsettings.json:
{
    "AppConfig": {
        "One": "First Default",
        "Two": "Second Default"
    }
}

ApiService/appsettings.json (Two is omitted and should be obtained from the default config of the AppHost):
{
    "AppConfig": {
        "One": "First is Overridden"
    }
}

I added the poco class for deserialization at the ServiceDefaults Project:
public class AppConfig
{
    public string? One { get; set; }
    public string? Two { get; set; }
}

This is the shared code to add the AppConfig class to the IServiceCollection in ServiceDefaults/Extensions.cs:
public static TBuilder AddCustomConfiguration<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder) where TBuilder : IHostApplicationBuilder
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(x => x.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("AppConfig").Get<AppConfig>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("AppConfig needs to be configured"));

    return builder;
}

Here it is used in ApiService/Program.cs:
// ...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add Custom Config:
builder.AddCustomConfiguration();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<SampleService>();
// ...

This is how i retrieve the information from the dependency injector in ApiService/SampleService.cs:
public class SampleService(AppConfig appConfig, ILogger<SampleService> logger) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("AppConfig.One: {One}", appConfig.One);
        logger.LogInformation("AppConfig.Two: {Two}", appConfig.Two);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Output:

"Two" is null. I want to get the default values configured in AppHost/appsettings.json.
How is the correct approach to "default" configurations in .NET Aspire?
I have made a sample app at: https://github.com/Lyra1337/net-aspire-default-configuration

In a standard scenario, you would add another configuration source via AddXXX() methods. But since you are aiming to create a shared default set of configuration values, you need to put this new source before other JSON settings files to avoid overwriting project-specific configuration values. Since I'd like to avoid merging two JSON files that share the same name (as I see it as avoidable difficulty), I propose a new, dedicated app settings file that would hold these shared default configuration values.
You can achieve that via the Insert() method, since the list of configuration sources is a normal, mutable list:
var source = new JsonConfigurationSource
{
    Optional = false,
    Path = "appsettings.Default.json",
    ReloadOnChange = true,
};
var firstJsonSource = builder.Configuration.Sources
    .OfType<JsonConfigurationSource>()
    .First();
var indexOfFirstJsonConfig = builder.Configuration.Sources.IndexOf(firstJsonSource);
builder.Configuration.Sources.Insert(indexOfFirstJsonConfig, source);

Some notes as to what is going on above. A new JsonConfigurationSource is manually created. Then, to insert it in the right place, the position of the first JSON source is found. Using that as a marker, a new source is inserted, offsetting the rest of the sources by a single position:

appsettings.Defaults.json
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json (optional)

Now, you need to make sure that the default settings file is copied to the output directory during compilation. You can place that file in an assembly of your choice, just make sure you have a project dependency set. I've put it in ServiceDefaults:

Right click with your mouse on appsettings.Defaults.json in solution explorer and select "Properties" (it's going to be at the very bottom). Then, make sure that "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "Copy if newer". See attached screen below:

When properly set, it will add these lines to your .csproj file:
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.Defaults.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>

Yet since appsettings.Defaults.json is coming from a different assembly, your application host will still not find it. Change the default configuration base path to output directory, where to appsettings.Defaults.json will be copied:
var domainPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(domainPath);

Complete solution
Extension methods for comfort of use:
public static class ConfigurationManagerExtensions
{
    public static void SetBasePathToCurrentAppDomain(this ConfigurationManager configurationManager)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(configurationManager);

        var domainPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        configurationManager.SetBasePath(domainPath);
    }

    public static void AddJsonFileBeforeOtherJson(
        this ConfigurationManager configurationManager,
        string filePath,
        bool optional,
        bool reloadOnChange)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(configurationManager);
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath);

        var source = new JsonConfigurationSource
        {
            Optional = optional,
            Path = filePath,
            ReloadOnChange = reloadOnChange,
        };
        var firstJsonSource = configurationManager.Sources
            .OfType<JsonConfigurationSource>()
            .First();
        var indexOfFirstJsonConfig = configurationManager.Sources.IndexOf(firstJsonSource);
        configurationManager.Sources.Insert(indexOfFirstJsonConfig, source);
    }
}

Usage in Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.SetBasePathToCurrentAppDomain();
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFileBeforeOtherJson("appsettings.Defaults.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);


I will share what I do for my microservices solution (I use just one solution so in case you have multiple solutions/repos evaluate if this method is useful for you), I have a Base project called  setup.csproj (is a classlib) there I create a baseprogram.cs with two methods create and run, create for build and run for app, all my web api's program.cs references this setup.csproj, and use the methods:
This is my products program.cs web api for example:
builder.AddServiceDefaults();

builder.Create(args, builderExtends => {

builder.Services.AddMssql<ProductsApiDbContext>("ProductsApiDbSqlServerConnection");

builder.AddHttpClients();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<Product, string>, ProductRepository>();
});


// Allow orchestration tools to detect the setup WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// this is in baseprogram.cs of setup.csproj
app.Run(appExtend => {
    app.MapDefaultEndpoints(); 
});

app.Run();

This is the BaseProgram.cs:
public static class DefaultWebApplicationSetup
{
    public static WebApplicationBuilder Create(
        this WebApplicationBuilder builder, 
        string[]? args = null,
        Action<WebApplicationBuilder>? webappBuilder = null, 
        Action<MvcOptions>? addControllerOptions = null
        )
    {

        // THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
        builder.Configuration
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Base.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Base.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange:true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .AddCommandLine(args ?? []);

        //-- YOU CAN SET THE OPTIONS HERE! AND ALL PROJECTS THAT
        // REFERENCE THIS SETUP WILL HAVE IT, THE OPTIONS SHOUL BE 
        // IN SETUP PROJECT AS SHARED FILES LIKE JWTSETTINGS, 
        // REDISSETTINGS AND OTHERS.
      
        
        builder.Services.AddFeatureManagement();
        
        //-- Cache
        builder.AddExternalCache("redis");
        
        //-- Register minimal endpoints and controllers

        //-- AuthN and AuthZ
        
        // CUSTOM BUILDER CONFIGURATION FOR EACH API
        if (webappBuilder != null)
        {
            webappBuilder.Invoke(builder);
        }

        return builder;
    }

    public static WebApplication Run(this WebApplication app, Action<WebApplication>? appExtend = null, bool callApiGateway = false)
    {
        // retrieve the config (FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT ONLY!!!)
        IConfiguration configuration = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        
        var configDictionary = configuration.AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

        foreach (var key in configDictionary.Keys)
        {
            var value = configDictionary[key];
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, value);
        }

        // Enable routing
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseExceptionHandler();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.MapSwagger();

            if (!callApiGateway) // api gateway has its own swaggerUI conf
            {
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
        }

        // always before hsts
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();

        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();

        // CUSTOM APP CONFGURATION FOR EACH API
        appExtend?.Invoke(app);

        return app;
    }
}

In the Setup project I create an appsettings.Base.json and appsettings.Base.Development.json and then i use this, to copy and paste for each build the base appsettings to each project (this goes on products.csproj and any other csproj that will use setup.csproj conf):
  <Target Name="CopySharedAppSettings" AfterTargets="Build">
    <!-- Define the source files -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <SharedFiles Include="..\..\..\Shared\Setup\appsettings.Base.json" />
      <SharedFiles Include="..\..\..\Shared\Setup\appsettings.Base.Development.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Copy files to the output directory -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SharedFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Base.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettingsa.Base.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

other solution of course net aspire can help with this using enviroment variables but you will have to create one for each key value configuration and pass it to each project (this is a good option for secrets)
